# pushing javascript $.get response into variable

Tags: javascript, get

how can I push the data I get from https://somelink.com into a variable that I can display?

--> for example, the response is in this format {"ABC":1435.21}

e.g. I want to display "The value of ABC is 1435.21"

Answer (score 0):

The response you are getting is **JSON** data, you can use that data like this

```
$.get( "https://somelink.com", function( data ) {
    //Get first key of JSON object as String
    let name = Object.keys(data)[0];
    //Get value by key name
    let value = data[name];
    //Output
    console.log("The value of "+name+" is "+value);
    alert("The value of "+name+" is "+value);
}, "json" );
```

The last parameter of $.get() tells that we will be receiving JSON formatted data from server.